# Connecting to BigQuery from execute Query

Tags: google-bigquery

Im working with Google Analytics 360 with a big client and I want to download all the data to BigQuery.

The objective is to have the data available to create some AI algorithms and make a deep analyse.

I want to connect to bigquery from a desktop SQL client like execute query, is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I want to connect to bigquery from a desktop SQL client like execute query, is this possible?

Check [`Simba Drivers for Google BigQuery`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/partners/simba-drivers/)

> > The intent of these drivers is to help users connect the power of Google BigQuery with existing tooling and infrastructure that does not have native integration. If you are building new integrations with BigQuery, we recommend you consider the native API. The functionality exposed by an ODBC/JDBC connection is necessarily a subset of the full capabilities of BigQuery.

Meantime, asking just in case - have you tried already Native UI? 
 - https://bigquery.cloud.google.com